# Subtract Variable if Present in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given I have:

`int1, int2, int3  =  1, nil, 3`

how would I subtract these `int`s from another variable, only if they weren't nil? I can write something sloppy, but I want a single line process if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
another_variable - [int1, int2, int3].compact.sum
```

Comment: `.compact.inject(:+)` if you are not using Rails

Answer (score 2):

```
othervariable - int1.to_i # will turn nil into 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like

```
ans = int1 && (int2-int1)
```